# About the neural network performance of classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification

I meet a problem that I'm making a 3 classification. There are 3 classes(label) of image. After training the neural network, we up load an image to recognize. The neural network give the prediction probability of this image like: A:50%  B:50%  C:70%.  So the result is that, this image below to label C. My question is that, the probability of label C is enough? Why enough or why not enough.

Comment: Because 1 > C > B >= A > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What activation function did you apply to last layer?
If you applied softmax function, sum of probability is 100%.
So, 50% 50% 70% is not valid.
And softmax function maps logits to exponential space, making output result sparse.
50% 50% 70% sparsity seems not enough if you applied softmax function, but it's not enough though, valid if dataset is so hard to classify.